# What is true formula for gas energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

So I was doing problem and used formula Eq.1 to find Energy in isochoric process. $$\Delta{E}=\frac{3}{2}pV$$
and get a bad result so now i saw the correct formula:
$$\Delta{E}=nc_v\Delta{T}$$
What is doing on? can somebody link consistent source of that formulas etc.?

Comment: What is the source of Eq.1?

Comment: $$ pV=nRT $$ this is suppopsed to be energy, 
i dont know nothing please help

Comment: "this is supposed to be energy" according to who? On what basis? Where did you get this information from?

Comment: sory, i dont ask for methodology. only how to get dE in isochoric process and why first equation takes to wrong answer

Comment: But you still haven’t told me where you got this information

Comment: For a mono-atomic ideal gas, $c_v=\frac{3}{2}R$

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, but I don't see how that translates into eq 1 of the OP for an isochoric process. It seems to me eq 1 should be $$\Delta E=\frac{3}{2}V\Delta p$$

Comment: @BobD That of course is correct.  I think the original. equation should just be $$E=\frac{3}{2}pV$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the two equations for an ideal (perfect) gas should be

$$E=\frac{3}{2}pV$$

and

$$E=nC_{v}T$$

Where the first equation can be derived from the second.

Proof:

For an ideal gas, any process, internal energy is a function of temperature only according to the following where $C_{v}$ is condidered independent of temperature

$$E=nC_{v}T$$

Although we normally deal with changes in internal energy and changes in temperature, this equation is based on assigning a value of zero to internal energy at absolute zero temperature.

Next, for an ideal gas we have

$$C_{v}=\frac{3}{2}R$$

Substituting into the equation for internal energy, we get

$$E=\frac{3}{2}nRT$$

From the ideal gas equation we have

$$pV=nRT$$

Finally, substituting this into the previous equation we get

$$E=\frac{3}{2}pV$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know, How do you get the first equation, and from the comments, it's clear that you may yourself don't know.

For the second equation, Use the first law of thermodynamics
$$\delta Q=dU+pdV$$
$$dU=\delta Q \ \ \ \ \ (dV=0\  \text{for isochoric process})$$
$$dU=C_VdT$$
$$\boxed{\Delta U=C_V\Delta T}$$
where $C_V$ is the specific heat of the gas.

Comment: It's valid only for an ideal gas.

Comment: Thank you for the responce. The source of eq. 1 was a youtube video and in can be fake. how can i know on this forum who answered  me is? $$C_v\Delta{T}=\frac{n}{2}V\Delta{p}$$

Comment: I'm unable to understand, Your English. For the below, if you are asking for  the proof,

Comment: $$pV=nRT\rightarrow Vdp=nRdT$$ As $dV=0$ for isochoric process, Thus $$\frac{C_V}{nR}Vdp$$ Now you can put delta instead of derivatives.